# Options for stopping SageMaker endpoint to avoid charges

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I followed one of the [Amazon SageMaker Examples from GitHub](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples) to train a model that would generate images:

1. First I set-up a [SageMaker Notebook instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/gs-setup-working-env.html) (ml.t2.medium), per the instructions.
2. Then, opened the running Jupyter notebook, went to `SageMaker Examples`, and selected one and clicked `Use`.
3. I uploaded some images, trained the model, and spent some time generating images.

The specific notebook example I ran used a `training_instance_type = "ml.g4dn.2xlarge"` and a `inference_instance_type = "ml.g4dn.2xlarge"`. In my case, I commented out the two following lines at the end of the notebook, because I didn't want to run that cell automatically and have to retrain the model.

```
#finetuned_predictor.delete_model()
#finetuned_predictor.delete_endpoint()
```

Since I'm using this for learning, I don't need any of the infrastructure running when I'm not using it. So I thought I disabled everything by going to `Amazon SageMaker >  Notebook instances`, and selecting `Actions>Stop` on the notebook instance I had created.

After checking billing, it looks like the inference instance is still incurring costs, since it's been running for 19+ hours:

[image: AWS billing showing hosting incurring most charges]

If I go to `Amazon SageMaker > Models`, I can see the model, but the only option is to delete it. There's no "start/stop".

If I go to `Amazon SageMaker > Endpoints`, I the endpoint is listed as "InService", but there isn't a start/stop option - only a "delete" action:

[image: Options under actions button]

What are my best options to avoid incurring costs when I'm not actively using models on SageMaker, but be able to restore when needed for demos, etc.? Should I just delete the **endpoint**, since that seems to be what incurs the charges, but keep the **model** around for re-use?

Answer (score 1):

SageMaker endpoints are used for real-time inference, and hence you only see the option for deploying/deleting the endpoint.
As you pointed out, you have a model and an endpoint config (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEndpointConfig.html) that could be persistent. You can create an endpoint from the endpoint config anytime.

Stopping the notebook does not stop training jobs that you've invoked from the notebook, or endpoints you have deployed.

Also try serverless inference (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html) if you're experimenting/for demos, so you're only paying per invocations rather than for the entire time the endpoint is in service.

Comment: Ah, serverless inference seems like it's ideal for my needs. Do I basically use the same model that was created via the notebook?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same model and use `ServerlessConfig` in your endpoint config, an examplet noebook here - https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/serverless-inference/Serverless-Inference-Walkthrough.ipynb

Comment: [@durga_sury](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458691/durga-sury)'s answer is great, however, I should point out that [Serverless Inference does not support GPU-enabled instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/serverless-endpoints.html#serverless-endpoints-how-it-works-exclusions) such as the `ml.g4dn.xlarge`.